# Pixelate an image with c# + xaml

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-8

I intend to **Pixelate** an image in an application **c# + xaml** for **Windows 8** (windows store app)
What is the best way to do this?

I found this code in C# ( http://notes.ericwillis.com/2009/11/pixelate-an-image-with-csharp/ ) but the namespace System.Drawing and Bitmap no longer exists.

Appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: I found a new solution (Creating a WinRT component using C + + / CX: Deform the Direct2D effect toolkit) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2012/08/13/creating-a-winrt-component-using-c-cx-deform-a-direct2d-effect-toolkit.aspx

Comment: `System.Drawing` certainly still exists (can you imagine the breaking change that would be?), but in a WPF app you will need to manually add a reference to it.  That said, it may not be the best choice for a WPF app anyway as they use different types.

Comment: You need to look at the type holding your image data in your WPF app, and modify Eric Will's code to use your data types.

Comment: Thanks for the comments
I forgot to mention that I am developing the application in windows 8 (windows app store)

Answer (score 4):

You just scale it twice, one down with interpolation, and a second back up without any interpolation.

Just calculate the "pixel" (segment) size by dividing the width and height on the segment size. This will be your new temporary size you scale down to.

By using interpolation you will get an approximated average of the color value when scaling/resizing down. Turning off interpolation when scaling up will create blocks of solid colors for each pixel, ie.pixelated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pixel shader right in the xaml. This tutorial (although for silverlight) has a pixelate example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight4trainingcourse_webcam_topic3.aspx